# My If statement is being skipped when I run this program

Tags: c++

I'm working on a programming problem and I cannot figure out why a particular if statement is being
skipped. The point of it is to check if a particular element in my array of characters is equal to a
"face card" i.e 'J' 'Q' or 'K' and then assign the value of 10 to a parallel array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void overTwentyOne(char* cards) {
    int total = 0;
    int cardsInt[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cards) + 1; i++) {
        
        if (cards[i] == 'J' || cards[i] == 'Q' || cards[i] == 'K') 
        cardsInt[i] == 10;
        cardsInt[i] = (int)cards[i] - ((int)'0');
        
    }
}
int main() {
    char cards[5] = { '1', '2', '3', 'J', '5' };
    overTwentyOne(cards);
}
```

The if statement that is skipped is `if (cards[i] == 'J' || cards[i] == 'Q' || cards[i] == 'K')`

as a side note line 10: `cardsInt[i] = (int)cards[i] - ((int)'0');` converts the ASCII value to an integer by subtracting the ASCII value of 0 from the ASCII value of the current subscript in the cards array.

Thank you! (also I see people get hate for using namespace std; on this site, I know why it's bad but for a small project like this it doesn't seem to matter)

Comment: Do you feel confident that you'll know when your program is too large to risk `using namespace std;`? I doubt it, which is why we recommend forming good habits from the start. Also, `sizeof(cards)` is not doing what you think. Just use a `std::vector` instead of arrays, which is another good habit to pick up early :)

Comment: `cardsInt[i] == 10;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `sizeof(cards)` is the size, in bytes, of a pointer (cards). It's not the size of the array cards points to

Comment: And even adding 1 to the right calculation involving `sizeof`, and then use it to index through the array, is also wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik silly mistake, forgive me I'm new to programming but even that is pretty silly for me, so does my compiler skip it entirely because it doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do anything. Then there's the obviously missing `else`, and also the wrong calculation involving `sizeof`. You can't use `sizeof` on a `char *` and somehow get the size of the pointed array. C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 1):

You want to *assign* to `cardsInt[i]`. Your line `==` *compares* the two operands.

Also, the `if` statement only applies to the line under it because it has no braces. There's no corresponding `else`, so `cardsInt[i] = (int)cards[i] - ((int)'0');` is always executed, and it overwrites `cardsInt[i]` to *not 10*. Change it to

```
if (cards[i] == 'J' || cards[i] == 'Q' || cards[i] == 'K') 
    cardsInt[i] = 10;
else
    cardsInt[i] = (int)cards[i] - ((int)'0');
```

Comment: Tbqh I would suggest putting even single lines in braces, especially for a beginner just learning. Getting into the habit of using braces to delineate blocks of code is helpful for doing C++, and it means that if you go back and realize that maybe you need two or three lines in one branch of a conditional, you don't have to remember to put the braces in when you add them.